# Cent OS issue - Not enough space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos7, software-raid

I have enough space but when i write new file in the var/www/html directory, it says not enough space

It is dedicated server with
Hard Drive2 x 480 GB SSD(Software-RAID 1)

I am running Cent OS 7

```
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        436G  126G  310G  29% /
devtmpfs        126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           126G   17M  126G   1% /run
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M  185M  277M  41% /boot
tmpfs            26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/0
```

I deleted some old file. now i can write. Why i cannot write file even i have enough space?

is this hardware issue?

i contacted hosting provider. Thay replied that

"Thank you very much for your message. Packages for our dedicated root servers and virtual servers do not include software support. The packages also do not include support for configuring these servers. For dedicated root and virtual servers, we only provide the hardware, network access and necessary infrastructure; and of course, we support our customers in case there are any failures or disruptions. Since you are a customer of one of our dedicated root servers or virtual servers, you are responsible for the configuration and administration of your server and for the software which runs on it."

Please help me on it

Thanks

---

i have now deleted some spaces

```
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# df -i
Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md2       29007872 12410945 16596927   43% /
devtmpfs       32977352      421 32976931    1% /dev
tmpfs          32982775        1 32982774    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          32982775      534 32982241    1% /run
tmpfs          32982775       13 32982762    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1         131072      344   130728    1% /boot
tmpfs          32982775        1 32982774    1% /run/user/0

[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        436G   54G  360G  14% /
devtmpfs        126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           126G   17M  126G   1% /run
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M  185M  277M  41% /boot
tmpfs            26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/0
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]#
```

Comment: Please, post the output of `df -i`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i have now deleted some old file. i have edited my question with both df -h and df -i

Comment: Is it working now? Did the "spaces" you deleted contain millions of files?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  yes working now. i deleted millions of file. i need to know why it got error that not enough space error for /dev/md2        436G  126G  310G  29% /

Comment: `df -i` shows the number of [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) free and in use. In a nutshell, this is the maximal number of files you can create in a file system. Currently, you have ~16M of them free for `/dev/md2` , but if you deleted millions of files, it might be that you had used up all inodes before. Unfortunately, the error message will be the same for a full disk and a full inode consumption, resulting in a "no space" error even if you have a large amount of free space left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's about full inode (maybe), check with `df -i` command

EDIT (added sven's relevant comment in the accepted answer)

`df -i` shows the number of inodes free and in use.

In a nutshell, this is the maximal number of files you can create in a file system. Currently, you have ~16M of them free for `/dev/md2` , but if you deleted millions of files, it might be that you had used up all inodes before.

Unfortunately, the error message will be the same for a full disk and a full inode consumption, resulting in a "no space" error even if you have a large amount of free space left

Comment: Maybe you want to elaborate your answer.